# How can a TikZ picture be used as an argument to memoir's fancy break?

Tags: tikz-pgf, memoir

Memoir style has \fancybreak{@@@} command that take arbitrary arguments. Is it possible to feed it a TikZ picture below and how?

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{knots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)--(1,0);
\filldraw (0,0) circle (3pt);
\filldraw (1,0) circle (3pt);
\end{tikzpicture} 

\fancybreak{@@@}

\end{document}
```

Comment: well sure, simply use it. You could define it as a command first to avoid to have to retype it all the time. Or store it in a box.

Answer (score 1):

As per @Ulrike Fischer's comment above, indeed it is very simple!

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{knots}

\begin{document}

\def\dumbell{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)--(1,0);
\filldraw (0,0) circle (3pt);
\filldraw (1,0) circle (3pt);
\end{tikzpicture} 
}
\fancybreak{\dumbell}

\end{document}
```

Another great tip by Ulrike!

Comment: Better use \newcommand instead of \def, with \def there is always the danger to overwrite an important existing command.